# How can I rewrite s domain name to the original IDN not the punycode?

Tags: mod-rewrite, dns, idn, punycode

I have bought an IDN domain name with non-latin characters. It is good but when I access the domain name, the address bar shows the punycode for the domain not the actual domain which will be hard for any user to remember.

Is there is anyway I can rewrite the domain name to the original IDN not the punycode?

example:
IDN = `افلاماونلاين.com`

punycode that show in address bar = `xn--mgbaaa1ksacgkcs1a.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that address bar is displayed is dependent on browser, its version, and possibly the used locale:

- regardless of the locale, I see `افلاماونلاين.com` in Opera 11
- I see `xn--mgbaaa1ksacgkcs1a.com` in Firefox 6 and Chrome 14 in my default locale (`cs_CZ`)
- however, when I set locale to `ar` in Chrome, it shows the original version of the IDN (like Opera)
- IE6 dies a horrible death (as expected)
- IE7 shows the punycoded version
- IE8 shows the punycoded version + an information button listing both versions

So, I'm afraid that there's not much that you can do about this as the site owner, unfortunately.